# What to learn after learning Objective-c for iphone programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

im im learning objective-c so i can program for the iphone and ipad. What do i learn next? cocoa? and then what else if any of you are developers please give me a list of what i need to learn 
Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How-to articles for iPhone development, Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405568/are-you-doing-iphone-development-how-do-you-learn

Comment: There are some good answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783321/whats-the-best-way-of-learning-iphone-programming-when-coming-from-java

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should instead ask yourself: what do I want to *do* next. And then as you think about that, you might realize that you need A, B, and C to be able to make that... and that's when you start learning those. That motivates you more than just learning something in a specific order.

Comment: Figuring out a project you want to work on, and focus on your own needs first rather than trying to think of The Next Big Thing, is the best way to figure what direction to go in. That was some of the best advice I ever received and it was a good idea to reiterate that here. +1

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, go for Cocoa... it's the logical next step. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you plan to develop… Cocoa Touch for sure, OpenGL ES for games, whatever other frameworks you will be using.