# Java for Iphone App Development?

Tags: java, iphone

I have been primarily using Java and have experience with it. I want to develop some iphone apps and wanted to know if there a way to develop iphone app using Java or iphone development can be only done using Objective-C?

Also if Objective-C is the only way to go then would really appreciate if you can recommend some books or links where I can get started on Iphone Development, my background is completely based on Java and I have not work with C or C++ professionally in the past.

Any recommendations/suggestions would highly help.

Can we have quick comparison of Objective-C vs Java or its like comparing oranges with Apple, am just trying to get some similarities in objective-c from java perspective so that I have some knowledge to leverage on while learning Objective-C, any suggestions?

Comment: if you are used to java, Objective-C looks pretty peculiar, esp the cumbersome syntax it features. You can get used to, though. Apple concepts of naming are also different from java and c++ world. The language is truly OO and the best part is that you can use C.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783321/whats-the-best-way-of-learning-iphone-programming-when-coming-from-java/5519526

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Iphone applications using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670874/create-iphone-applications-using-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430223693) is a book found through a quick google search for java developers to learn objective C.  I used other books in this series (Learn Objective-C on the Mac, and Beginning iPhone Development) to learn iPhone development, so I assume it is good.

And [here](http://jonathanlehr.files.wordpress.com/2009/09/objective-c-and-java.pdf) is a link to a well done powerpoint presentation given on comparing Java to Objective-C (about halfway is where the syntax differences start with examples!) as well as some of the cool features of Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but Java or any JIT'ed language is not possible on the iPhone/iPad.

You might want to look at mono and use C#, it is closer to Java than Objective-C.

Mono Touch
- http://monotouch.net/

Or Unity 3d.
- http://unity3d.com/

Both use mono...

The mono group is re-grouping as a [startup company](http://www.xamarin.com/) and aims to be on par with novel's offering within a couple of months.   It still looks like a good piece of technology and well worth a look.

http://tirania.org/blog/

Comment: How does it work basically? I have never used C# in past but have heard a lot about it.

Comment: For mono touch have a peek at following tutorial @ http://monotouch.net/Tutorials/MonoDevelop_HelloWorld and for C# itself.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you can't use Java for iOS development. In my opinion, the only reason to use C or C++ would be legacy/interoperability compatibility, or if you were extensively familiar with those languages. Since you're not, I'd advise biting the bullet and learning Objective C. I've just done so recently (although admittedly I come from a C background) and found it pretty straightforward.

I'd say start here, in general:
http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action
and here, a bit more specifically:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneGeneral/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007853
and here, for a good hands-on runthrough:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514

I know that looks like I'm just saying RTFM, but that's what I did (read through all those articles while walking through the "hello world" app) and I found it to be an effective teaching method.
And of course, use SO for any specific questions you may have.
Good luck.

Comment: I didn't know about MonoTouch; I stand corrected. Pretty cool, if it does what it advertises.

Comment: Is Objective-C object oriented or along the lines of Java or C#? Can we do quick comparison between java and objective-c?

Comment: @Rachel: That question is a bit beyond the scope of a comment. If you'd like a more elaborate take from me, please let me know or ask a new question. Jesse Naugher's answer also has some good suggestions.
In summary, Objective-C is object oriented, but it feels much more like C++ to me than C# or Java. I'd say the main base difference is Objective-C's memory management scheme (no garbage collection in iOS) and the fact that you still have to actively understand and use pointers, whereas all that is abstracted/managed in C# and Java. The rest mostly balances or is dependent on the framework.

Comment: Thanks for the Information. It is certainly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop iOs apps with Objective C, C/C++(but you have to use some objective c with it) also you can develop with Javascript frameworks. Search: Titanium, SenchaTouch for that. 
Java is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check out:
http://www.xmlvm.org/iphone/

I've never tried it, but it seemed interesting at least .  I'd expect the performance would be subpar, however.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the project :

http://www.in-the-box.org/

enabling translation of an android application into ios one

Answer (score 0):

There is a new cross platform framework which provides Java API's and tools to create mobile native apps(ios, android, rim, win7 and j2me ) and it's FOSS software.
http://www.codenameone.com/